# Error occurred while execute main calls on jar file

Tags: java

While I am running Main class related to Jar file I got following error. Some one please help me. Thanks.

```
D:\data\Gateway\dist>java -jar Gateway.jar com.Application
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext
```

indicates that the jar `org.springframework.context` must be added to the classpath.

Comment: Hi Vakh !
Thanks a lot for the freed back. 
Have a nice time !
Thanks.